# Changing hostname in Shindig's container

Tags: apache-shindig

I'm using Shindig 2.0 with its default container.
When the container renders the gadget, it calls the servlet: `/gadgets/ifr?url=http://iltlvl094:8080/sample-gadget/spec.xml&libs=rpc&parent=http://iltlvl094&debug=1&#rpctoken=54612318`

This servlet returns HTML code that imports JavaScript file from `localhost`:

`<script src="http://localhost:8080/gadgets/js/rpc.js?container=default&amp;nocache=0&amp;debug=1&amp;c=0&amp;v=249039fb66d20be125366df4d5ec26c2"></script>`

Why it's referring `localhost` and not the actual hostname - `iltlvl094`?
Where I can change it?

I'm using Shindig out of the box, thus I don't have any source code or configuration files to modify. Maybe I can do this via command line arguments?

Thanks,
Tomer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how I can do that. There are two ways:

1. Add system property: -Dshindig.host=my_host -Dshindig.port=my_port
2. Add to the web.xml: shindig.host=my_host and shindig.port=my_port